# Really strange NullPointerException in RoboVM

Tags: ios, nullpointerexception, robovm

If I call the following RoboVM method with any **non-null** argument:

```
public static void runOnUiThread(final Runnable runnable) {
    System.out.println("Inside runOnUiThread():");
    System.out.println("  Null-check: "+(runnable==null));

    NSOperation operation = new NSOperation() {

        @Override
        public void main() {
            System.out.println("Inside main():");
            System.out.println("  Null-check: "+(runnable==null));
            runnable.run();                 // NullPointerException here?!? How???
            System.out.println("  main() completed");
        }
    };

    NSOperationQueue.getMainQueue().addOperation(operation);        
}
```

it outputs:

```
Inside runOnUiThread():
  Null-check: false
Inside main():
  Null-check: true
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at RoboVMTools$1.main(RoboVMTools.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.foundation.NSOperation.$cb$main(NSOperation.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at Main.main(Main.java)
```

What on earth is going on??? And more importantly, how can I work around it?

- I tried adding `operation.addStrongRef(runnable);` right before `NSOperationQueue...`. No difference.
- I also tried moving the anonymous inner class into its own class that has a `private final` field to store the runnable which is passed into its constructor. Same result.

Am I just missing something totally obvious???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the GC. Your `NSOperation` instance is garbage collected before the operation is invoked from the Objective-C side. When `NSOperationQueue` calls into the Java side a new instance of your `NSOperation` anonymous class will be created which doesn't have a reference to the `Runnable` instance but rather `null` and the result is a `NullPointerException` getting thrown.

The way you resolved it using `addStrongRef()` is correct though only the `mainQueue.addStrongRef(operation)` and the corresponding `removeStrongRef()` calls should be sufficient:

```java
public static void runOnUiThread(final Runnable runnable) {

    final NSOperationQueue mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.getMainQueue();

    NSOperation operation = new NSOperation() {

        @Override
        public void main() {
            runnable.run();
            mainQueue.removeStrongRef(this);
        }
    };

    mainQueue.addStrongRef(operation);
    mainQueue.addOperation(operation);      
}
```

This will prevent the Java `operation` instance (and any Java objects reachable from it like the `Runnable`) from being GCed until the Objective-C `NSOperationQueue` instance is deallocated. As the Objective-C side queue is a singleton it won't get deallocated during the lifetime of the app.

The RoboVM `NSOperationQueue` Java class provides a version of the `addOperation()` method that takes a `Runnable`. When using this method RoboVM will take care of retaining the `Runnable` instance while it's needed by the Objective-C side for you. The same is true for any method that takes a `@Block` annotated parameter of type `Runnable` or any of the `org.robovm.objc.block.VoidBlock*` or `org.robovm.objc.block.Block*` interfaces.

Using this `addOperation()` method your code simply becomes:

```java
public static void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
    NSOperationQueue.getMainQueue().addOperation(runnable);      
}
```

PS. The GC used by RoboVM has nothing to do with the Apple garbage collector so Apple's docs won't help you understand problems like this.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you. +1 for `addOperation(Runnable)`. I completely missed that! :) By the way: RoboVM is absolutely amazing! I am sooooo glad I don't have to deal with Objective-C (yuck!)! You guys are awesome! Thank you so much! The best day of my life will be when there's a RoboVM-version that can build apps for Windows Phone! ;) Would that be hard, given the infrastructure you already have? Or are you already working on it? :)

Comment: I'm happy to hear that you like RoboVM! No, we're not working on Windows Phone support. MS recently announced [Project Astoria](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/uwp-bridges/project-astoria) which will bring Android apps to Windows Phone. Once that's out porting RoboVM to Windows Phone will not make much sense. Would have been an interesting challenge though... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well... This fixes it:

```
public static void runOnUiThread(final Runnable runnable) {

    final NSOperationQueue mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.getMainQueue();

    NSOperation operation = new NSOperation() {

        @Override
        public void main() {
            runnable.run();

            mainQueue.removeStrongRef(runnable);
            mainQueue.removeStrongRef(this    );
        }
    };

    mainQueue.addStrongRef(runnable );
    mainQueue.addStrongRef(operation);

    mainQueue.addOperation(operation);      
}
```

But don't ask my why this is necessary. The Apple docs say ["In garbage-collected applications, the queue strongly references the operation object."](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperation:) So, `operation.addStrongRef(runnable);` as I tried earlier should have been sufficient as the operation object should be referenced by the queue anyways. But I guess the world doesn't always work the way I interpret the documentation.